# how do I get a list of columns in a sql table that are not in another table?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

table A has 125 columns. table B has 123 columns.

```
select * from (desc A full outer join desc B on A.col_name = B.col_name)
```

the result of this should have null corresponding to missing columns.

why doesn't this work and throw the error `mismatched input 'from' expecting <EOF>`

Answer (score 0):

`DESCRIBE` will not work like that in the `FROM` clause, instead, you can achieve your desired results like below:

```
val df_a = spark.sql("desc table_1").select($"col_name" as "colA")
val df_b = spark.sql("desc table_2").select($"col_name" as "colB")

val schema_diff = df_a.join(df_b,df_a("colA")===df_b("colB"),"fullouter")
schema_diff.show()
```

output:

```
+----+----+
|colA|colB|
+----+----+
|dept|null|
|  id|  id|
|name|name|
+----+----+
```